# How to display a multi dimensional array in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have this class

```
public class Step {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int id;
}
```

My servlet creates a two dimensional array of it as follows:

```
Step[][] steps = new Step[size][size];
```

Some of steps are `null`, some of steps are not `null`. Then it forwards to JSP as follows:

```
request.setAttribute("gamesSteps", steps);          
request.getRequestDispatcher("/game.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In JSP, I'm displaying them as follows:

```
< c:forEach items="${requestScope.gamesSteps}" var="steps"> 
    < c:forEach items="${steps}" var="step">                   
        < c:out value="${step.id} "/>       
    < /c:foreach>     
< /c:forEach>
```

But nothing shows up. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need getter methods for your attributes.

add

```
public int getId() {
 return id;
}
```

to your class.

You have to obey the the JavaBeans specification.

Answer (score 0):

You have some typing errors. Try it this way.

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.gamesSteps}" var="steps"> 
<c:forEach items="${steps}" var="step">                   
    <c:out value="${step.id} "/>       
</c:forEach>     
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I believe that the OP purposefully inserted them while trying to figure how to get the HTML code to show up in the Stack Overflow question preview, before he discovered the code formatting button, but forgot to remove the whitespace afterwards. Thus, that was just a red herring.

Comment: I was referring to < /c:foreach> it won't work with small e and the space between < and /

Comment: I was also referring to that :)